# Chat messenger app design questions? JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, chat, messenger

I'm currently working on a trading market program for players of a game. For the messenger part of it, which players will use to communicate, I just have a few questions on how it should be setup.

- The messenger window will use a ListView (named 'chatListView') with a cell factory for 'Chat' objects
- The 'Chat' object will have a String getOriginUsername() which will be the text displayed in the ListView cell itself
- The messenger window will have a Text Area (named 'chatDisplay')for the messages stored in an ArrayList of Strings inside of the 'Chat' object
- Upon receiving a message, the client will add the message to the matching 'Chat' object's ArrayList
- The message should then be displayed in the text area

My question is.. How am I going make the Messenger realize that a new string has been added to the ArrayList, and have it know to update the text area? The 'Chat' object has a method to append a message to it's corresponding ArrayList in the 'Chat', but the ListView is already populated with the 'Chat's. Since it is already populated, it is not going to be listening for changes inside each 'Chat' object. How can I implement something like this?

Because the ListView cell itself needs to be listening for changes (if the cell is selected, in other words..if the chat is open and a chat is happening now), I will need to add some kind of listener to the cells themselves, right?

For example..Using the Chat objects method to append to the 'Chat's message arraylist, upon an inbound message do something like:

```
 chatListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().appendMessage("This is a message");
```

Then, have the appended message be displayed to the main messages Text Area 'chatDisplay'.

How exactly do I go about doing this? I just couldn't really find what I was looking for by doing a search..or more likely perhaps I couldn't think of the correct wording to do a proper search.

Chat class:

```
package tarkov.trader.objects;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Chat extends Form {


public boolean isNew;
private String origin;   // This string will be a client's username that initiated the chat
private String destination;   // This string will be a client's username receiving the new chat
private ArrayList<String> messages;   // The arraylist will hold strings of messages between clients


public Chat(String origin, String destination, ArrayList<String> messages)
{
    this.type = "chat";
    this.isNew = true;
    this.origin = origin;
    this.destination = destination;
    this.messages = messages;
}


// Getters:
public String getOrigin()
{
    return origin;
}


public String getDestination()
{
    return destination;
}


public ArrayList<String> getMessages()
{
    return messages;
}


public String getName(String clientName)
{
    if (origin.equals(clientName))
        return destination;
    else
        return origin;
}



// Setters:
public void setOpened()   // Server calls this upon receiving and recognizing the chat is 'new'
{
    this.isNew = false;
}


public void setMessages(ArrayList<String> messages)
{
    this.messages = messages;
}


public void appendMessage(String message)
{
    if (this.messages == null)
    {
        this.messages = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    this.messages.add(message);
}

}
```

Here is my list view cell factory.. and setting on action to unpack the arraylist of messages, then display in the text area 'chatDisplay'

```
        // List view 
    chatListView = new ListView<>();
    chatListView.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<Chat>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Chat chat, boolean empty)
        {
            super.updateItem(chat, empty);

            if (empty || chat == null)
            {
                this.setText(null);
                this.setGraphic(null);
            }
            else
            {
                this.setText(chat.getName(TarkovTrader.username));
                this.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/chat.png"), 24, 24, true, true)));
                this.setPrefHeight(45);
                });
            }
        }
    });
chatListView.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
 unpackChatMessages(chatListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getMessages());

});
```

For good measure, the unpackChatMessages method:

```
private boolean unpackChatMessages(ArrayList<String> messageList)
{
    chatDisplay.setText(null);

    if (messageList == null)
        return false;

    for (String message : messageList)
    {
        append(message);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You mention “Upon receiving a message” but I don’t see a new message String in any of your code.  Currently, you’re just calling unpackChatMessages with the existing messages.  I would expect a new message to be received over a socket or some other communication channel.

Comment: model your logic, then bind all view state to properties of that model